# angular audio play on ngoninit not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, audio, ngoninit

html code:

```
<audio id="notification" src="../assets/audio/notification.mp3" autoplay="true"
muted="muted"></audio>
```

ts code:

```
 let audioPlayer = <HTMLAudioElement> document.getElementById('notification');
      audioPlayer.muted = false;
      audioPlayer.play();
```

I am getting error play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

Answer (score 0):

You should not query audioPlayer on init.
The audio needs a bit of time to be ready.

You should trigger muted and play when Html Audio can play. (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplay.asp)

or Using ViewChild decorator.
(https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)